# How to place an XML file in form of a String inside Java file

Tags: java, eclipse, xml

I am using Eclipse IDE
I have a big XML file .
I wan to copy this XML file and provide it in form of a String .

```
String XMLStringSource = "XML Content Here" ;
```

I am getting errros with double quotes in the XML file , please tell me how can we resolve this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure Eclipse to escape text when pasting into a string literal.

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing.
- Select the checkbox which says "Escape text when pasting into a string literal".
- Press Apply.

Now create a String literal e.g.

```
String xml = "";
```

Copy your xml and paste it inside the quotes. Eclipse will automatically escape it for you.

This is quite handy for small bits of xml or text.

If you have a large file, then you should read the file into a string instead.

Comment: Great , its working and you saved a lot of time . dogbane , thanks once again.

Answer (score 4):

You should not do that. In fact, it is impossible beyond a certain size as there is a limit of 64KB on the bytecode of methods (which include initializers).

The correct way to do it is put the XML file next to the source code and use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yow will need to escape the quotes. But this will change the look of XML; it will be a combination of Java String/XML. Also if the the XML file is big like you say then you will need to do a search and replace for quotes `"` with escaped quotes `\"` before pasting into the java file.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
            {
                FileReader fstream = new FileReader("D:\\File.xml");
                BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(fstream);
                String y="";
                while ((y=out.readLine()) != null)  {
                    System.out.println(y);
                }
                //out.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

is this acceptable? just read the file line by line, the String variable will have double quotations and they wont generate an error. If reading step by step can solve problem.